# Difficulty resolving white space below my webpage

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I am a noob at HTML/CSS, and I'm trying to put a timeline on my website. I've run into a strange issue: I have a weird block of space under my #timeline class anytime I try to change the height.

What I've tried: I've read some posts about absolute/relative positioning and how if you try to change the height with An absolute or relatively positioned object, it will leave a gap of space between where it is and where it used to be.

With this information, I'm not sure how to reposition my timeline elements without using absolute positioning, because I don't want the timeline to be too large. Any recommendations or tips would be great. here's my code (please view in full window - timeline has some compatibility issues with safari right now:( use chrome if you can)

My CSS is kind of long, but I wanted you to see the whole webpage and understand how It all worked together. I experienced the issue after styling the body and #timeline component, so I believe the styling below these components is causing the issues.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

```css
html{
 font-size: 10px;
 font-family: Raleway;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: linear-gradient(#FF9940, white);
 font-weight: normal;

}

h1{
 font-family: Raleway;
 padding: 20px;
 font-size: 53px;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px grey;
 background-color: #1E2752;
 text-align: center;
 border: 5px solid black;
 color: #FCFCFF;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

li{
 float: left;
 padding-right: 30px;
}

li a{

display: block;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 19px 16px;
border: 2px solid #ffffff;
right: -100px;

}

li a:hover{
color: #ffffff;
background: #FF9940;
transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}


ul{
transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
list-style-type: none; 
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 12px;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #ffffff;
background: transparent;
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
padding: 0px;
top: 28px;
left: 23px;
right: 23px;
width: 100%;
}

h2{
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 25px;
}

h2 p{
 font-size: 18px;
}

.right-button{
  float: right;
  padding-right: 47px
  
}

.other-button{
 float: right;
 padding-right: 30px;
}

body{
 font-family: tahoma;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 1.75;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;


}

#timeline{
 margin-left: 470px;
 height: 400px;
 width: 500px;
 display:flex;
 background-color: #031625;
}

#timeline:hover .t1-item{
 max-width: 400px;
 max-height: 500px;
 width:23.3333%;
}

.t1-item:before, .t1-item:after{

 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 content: ' ';
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 
}
.t1-item{

 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 position: relative;
 width: 25%;
 height: 100vh;
 min-height: 600px;
 color:white;
 overflow: hidden;
 transition: width 0.5s ease;
}

.t1-item:after{

 background: rgba(3,22,37,0.85);
 opacity: 1;
 transition: opacity .5s ease;
}

.t1-item:before{
 
 
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, 
 rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 75%);

 z-index: 1;
 opacity: 0;
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0) translateY(50%);
 transition: opacity .5s ease,
 transform .5s ease;

}

.t1-item:hover{

 width: 30%;
}

.t1-item:hover:after{
 
 opacity: 0;
}

.t1-item:hover:before{
 
 opacity: 1;
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0) translateY(0);
 transition: opacity 1s ease, transform 1s ease
 .25s;
}

.t1-item:hover .t1-content{

 opacity: 1;
 transform: translateY(0);
 transition: all .75s ease .5s;
}

.t1-item:hover .t1-bg{

 filter: grayscale(0);
}

.t1-content{
 
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0) translateY(25px);
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0.1618em;
 top: 55%;
 opacity: 0%;

}

.t1-content h3{

 font-family: tahoma;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #1779cf;
 font-size: 1.44rem;
 font-weight: normal;
}

.t1-year{

 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 border-top: 1px solid white;
 border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.t1-year p{

 font-family: tahoma;
 font-size: 1.628rem;
 line-height: 0;

}

.t1-bg{

 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center center;
 transition: filter .5se ease;
 filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en" >

 <head>
  <meta charset = "UTF-8">
  <title> Isabelle Kreienbrink </title>
  <link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1> Header </h1>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#resume">Resume</a></li>
    <li><a href="#academics">Academics</a></li>
    <li><a href="#projects" >Projects</a></li>
    <li class="right-button"><a href="#contacts">Contact Info</a></li>
    <li class="other-button"><a href="#other">Test</a></li>
    <li class="other-button"><a href="#other">Testing</a></li>
   </ul>
  <h2> Welcome to my website! 
   <p> I hope you learn a little about me while you're here. </p>
  </h2>

  <section id="timeline">
   <div class="t1-item">
    <div class="t1-bg" style="background-image:url(https://eng-dev.stanford.edu/sites/default/files/styles/full_width_banner_tall/public/chalkboard_web.jpg?itok=xqk3ef56)">
    </div>

    <div class="t1-year">
     <p class="f2 heading">2014</p>
    </div>

    <div class="t1-content">
     <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor </h3>
     <p>
      test
     </p>
    </div>

   </div>



   <div class="t1-item">
    <div class="t1-bg" style="background-image:url(001.jpeg)"></div>

    <div class="t1-year">
    <p class="f2 heading">2015</p>
    </div>

    <div class="t1-content">
     <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor </h3>
     <p>
      test
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="t1-item">
    <div class="t1-bg" style="background-image:url(001.jpeg)"></div>

    <div class="t1-year">
    <p class="f2 heading">2016</p>
    </div>

    <div class="t1-content">
     <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor </h3>
     <p>
      test
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="t1-item">
    <div class="t1-bg" style="background-image:url(001.jpeg)"></div>

    <div class="t1-year">
    <p class="f2 heading">2015</p>
    </div>

    <div class="t1-content">
     <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor </h3>
     <p>
      test
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>

  </section>


 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i'm understanding your problem correctly, it's the .t1-item {height: 100vh;} that's giving you the issue, along with the min-height: 600px. That is pushing the .t1-item down in its pre-hover state, thus creating that space.

An alternative to using these height specifications would be to use margin-top to position your instances of .t1-item:

```
.t1-item {
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
position: relative;
width: 25%;
color: white;
overflow: hidden;
transition: width 0.5s ease;
margin-top: 20rem;
}
```

Comment: That was the issue! I'm going to read up about those styling properties. I marked your answer as correct. Thank you!